# Synology NAS X-Fer Speed Possible Issues

Tags: cache, ssd, network-attached-storage, benchmark, synology

I recently purchased a Synology DS1815+ 8-Bay NAS for my organization and I have been running benchmarks all morning.

I purchased:

- 4 x 4TB 7200RPM HGST NAS (Enterprise) drives &
- 2 X 256GB Samsung 850PRO SSD's

I have tried a few different configurations.

- 4 X 4TB in SHR (synology hybrid raid 1 disk fault tolerance) with AND WITHOUT SSD CACHE **GOT THE SAME PERFOMANCE WITH OR WITHOUT SSD CACHE**
- 2 x 256GB SSD in both RAID 1 and RAID 0

Long story short I have gotten almost exactly the same performance on ALL these configurations:
**Approx 106MB/s - 116MB/S READ AND WRITE**

All of this is connected with CAT6 Cables, gigabit switch and all brand new hardware. Tests included "Nas performance tester 1.7" and simply copying large video files to and from the drives to my Laptop (w/ m.2 ssd & gigabit lan).

Now although I am not complaining at those speeds, they will likely be enough to accomplish what I want to with this setup I am disappointing in the lack of improvement from SSD's either in cache or in dedicated volumes of their own.

**MY QUESTIONS:**

- What am I doing wrong here if anything?
- Is there any Synology-side settings I need to change to improve this?
- Any other input is appreciated!

Comment: 116MB/sec is over 90% utilization of a single gigabit link.  That's pretty damn impressive to me.  What sort of performance are you expecting?  You'll never get 100% (125MB) due to the overhead of tcp/udp and whatever underlying protocol(s) you're using to access it.

Comment: Well it does have 4 gigabit ports. Perhaps I could do link aggregation of some kind? Looking to see if anyone has made any changes like that or had any experience using that. I know I could configure multi-channel over iSCSI targets however I wasn't sure of my other options.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: After more benchmarks and more digging it looks like if I want any improvement I would have to move up 800 bucks to a Synology DS2015XS that has 2 x 10GB SFP ports..... woops